# AKS Dapr rabbitMQ component - Daprd Sidecar not running

Tags: .net, azure-aks, dapr

I have rabbitMQ running on http://xyzip:5672 and credentials sampleusername, samplepassword, created the rabbitMQ component yaml file created.

```
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: componentName
  namespace: samplenamespace
spec:
 type: pubsub.rabbitmq
 version: v1
 metadata:
 - name: connectionString
   value: "amqp://xyzip:5672"
 - name: protocol
   value: amqp
 - name: hostname
   value: 10.22.39.162
 - name: username
   value: sampleusername
 - name: password
   value: samplepassword
 - name: consumerID
   value: pubsub-subscriber
 - name: durable
   value: false
 - name: deletedWhenUnused
   value: false
 - name: autoAck
   value: false
 - name: deliveryMode
   value: 0
 - name: requeueInFailure
   value: false
 - name: prefetchCount
   value: 0
 - name: reconnectWait
   value: 0
 - name: concurrencyMode
   value: parallel
 - name: publisherConfirm
   value: false
 - name: enableDeadLetter # Optional enable dead Letter or not
   value: true
 - name: maxLen # Optional max message count in a queue
   value: 3000
 - name: maxLenBytes # Optional maximum length in bytes of a queue.
   value: 10485760
 - name: exchangeKind
   value: fanout
 - name: saslExternal
   value: false
 - name: ttlInSeconds
   value: 60
 - name: clientName
   value: pubsub-subscriber
 - name: heartBeat
   value: 10s
```

The dapr service sidecar is giving below error.

**Fatal error from runtime: process component dapr-pubsub error: [INIT_COMPONENT_FAILURE]: initialization error occurred for dapr-pubsub (pubsub.rabbitmq/v1): init timeout for component dapr-pubsub (pubsub.rabbitmq/v1) exceeded after 5s**

Answer (score 0):

In-order to configure rabbitMQ on AKS, kindly follow below steps-
Here I will be using bitnami charts for rabbitMQ for the setup.

1. Assuming that you have a working AKS cluster with helm installed on it as below.
   [image]

[image]

2. Run `helm list` command to verify if any charts already present. If not, you will search for the rabbitmq repo using `helm search repo rabbitmq` , add the repo using `helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami`, update the repo to keep things upto-date using `helm repo update` and verify your rabbitMQ details using `helm show values bitnami/rabbitmq`
3. Now install the rabbitMQ using `helm install my-release bitnami/rabbitmq`.
   [image]
   [image]
4. Once installed, you will get your login credentials on your screen. Save them and map your ports as shown above using `kubectl port-forward --namespace default svc/my-release-rabbitmq 15672:15672`
   Once the port is mapped, you should see something like this-
   [image]

Now go to your browser and type `localhost:15672`
and you are on the login page of rabbitMQ
[image]

5. Key in the credentials which you have saved from your previous step and you have successfully logged into rabbitMQ dashboard.
   [image]

In order to install dapr on your AKS
Follow the below steps-
Here I am using helm charts instead of dapr CLI and I will be installing version 1.12.

```
helm repo add dapr https://dapr.github.io/helm-charts/
helm repo update
```

Once the repo is downloaded, verify the available version using

```
helm search repo dapr --devel --versions
```

[image]

Install dapr with your preferred version.

```
helm upgrade --install dapr dapr/dapr --version=1.12 --namespace dapr-system --create-namespace --set global.ha.enable=true --wait
```

Now if you check, dapr is installed
[image]

and pods are active
[image]

When encountering a `Fatal error from runtime` indicating an initialization timeout for a Dapr component, it's important to narrow down the issue systematically. Below are the steps to diagnose and potentially resolve the problem with your Dapr RabbitMQ pub/sub component:
Start by ensuring that your RabbitMQ instance is running and reachable from your AKS cluster:

```
kubectl run -it --rm --image=busybox --restart=Never rabbitmq-test -- \
sh -c 'nc -vz xyzip 5672'
```

If the connection fails, your RabbitMQ instance might not be accessible from within the cluster, or the service address/port might be incorrect.
Next, check the logs of the Dapr sidecar container for more detailed error messages:

```
kubectl logs <your-pod-name> -c daprd -n <namespace>
```

Also ensure there are no AKS network policies or Azure Network Security Groups blocking communication between the Dapr sidecar and RabbitMQ:

```
kubectl describe netpol --all-namespaces
```

Reference documents-
[MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/microservices-dapr?tabs=bash,azure-cli)
[Dapr Doc](https://docs.dapr.io/operations/hosting/kubernetes/kubernetes-deploy/)
[Rabbitmq Doc](https://docs.dapr.io/reference/components-reference/supported-pubsub/setup-rabbitmq/)